# xgboost not recognizing custom metric

Tags: python-3.x, xgboost

I cant get my custom f1 score to run on xgb cross validation, how do i get it to work?

here is my custom f1 score:

```py
def f1_eval(y_pred, dtrain): 

    y_true = dtrain.get_label()

    err = 1-f1_score(y_true, np.round(y_pred)) 

    return 'f1_err', err
```

Here is how i want to run xgboost:

```py
if classifier_name in ["gbtree", "gblinear", "dart"]:

   param['tree_method'] = 'hist'


   param["eval_metric"] = f1_val#'mlogloss'


   param['booster'] = classifier_name


   param['num_class'] = 5


   param['n_jobs']=-1

xgb_cv = cv(dtrain=data_dmatrix, params=param, nfold=5,
num_boost_round=50, early_stopping_rounds=10,)
```

this is the error i get:

`Unknown metric function \<function f1_eval at 0x7fa0b35ea9d0\>`